# How to use the `verify` method in controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and in my controllers I would like to use the `verify` method this way:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  verify :params      => "user",
         :only        => :update,
         :redirect_to => {:action => 'settings'}

  ...
end
```

However, when I access the browser page that calls the `update` controller action (or any other controller action) I get the following error:

```
Routing Error
undefined method `verify' for UsersController:Class
```

How can I solve the problem? Where I can find some documentation about the `verify` method?

---

*Note*: The `verify` method is described in "*The Rails 3 Way*" book (at *page 111*) written by Obie Fernandez.

Comment: Erm, what `verify` method are you talking about? There's no method in Rails like that so far as I know.

Comment: Checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/action_controller_overview.html#verification. From what I see here. This got into rails at 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say but `verify` method is no longer available in Rails 3.2.  It was last used in Rails v2.3.8

Some of the verify are
http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/activesupport/lib/active_support/message_verifier_rb.html

or you find some useful verify & valid methods in Active_support/Multibyte/utils.rb

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/67d8b9743add53f908ca417c641c4a54dd326c7d/activesupport/lib/active_support/multibyte/utils.rb

Hope this helps.